# What is the relationship between loop invariant and weakest precondition

Tags: formal-methods, formal-verification, loop-invariant, formal-semantics, hoare-logic

Given a loop invariant, Wikipedia lists, a nice way to produce the weakest preconditions for a loop
(from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predicate_transformer_semantics):

```
wp(while E inv I do S, R) = 
    I \wedge
    \forall y. ((E \wedge I) \implies wp(S,I \wedge x < y))[x <- y] \wedge
    \forall y. ((\neg E \wedge I) \implies R)[x <- y]
where y is a tuple of fresh variables.
```

M[x <- N] substitutes all the occurrences of x in M with N.

Now, my problem is the variable y.  The \forall y, binds y in the expression, so "y is a tuple of fresh variables" doesn't parse for me.  Is the y bound in the \forall, the same as the y in "[x <- y]"?  I simply cannot parse the above.

Edit: Rephrased to avoid reference request.

My question is: what the direct connection between loop invariants and computing weakest preconditions, if any.  It seems a lot of things done in practice relax weakest precondition for loops to a precondition that is suitable for verification.  The above from wikipedia suggests that given a loop invariant, one can indeed compute the weakest preconditions on the nose, but I am having trouble understanding this condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax “x <- y” in the rule that you quote means the simultaneous substitution of several variables that we can assume to be named x<sub>1</sub>, x<sub>2</sub>, … x<sub>n</sub> respectively by other variables y<sub>1</sub>, y<sub>2</sub>, … y<sub>n</sub> which, as you point out, are bound immediately above in the formula by a \forall.

The way to apply the rule in practice is to pick a set of variables occurring in the predicate `R`. The number and the name of these variables is left to the choice of the person who applies the rule, but it must be possible to define a well-founded relation `<` between tuples of the chosen arity such that `\forall y. ((E \wedge I) \implies wp(S,I \wedge x < y))[x <- y]` will be provable eventually.

This is what the wikipedia article means when it says “Weakest-precondition of while-loop is usually parametrized by a predicate `I` called loop invariant, and a well-founded relation on the space state denoted `<` and called loop variant.” It is not just `I` that must have been chosen in advance and must decorate the program, there is also the choice of a number of variables of the program modified in the body of the loop `S` and occurring in the condition `E`, and the existence of the well-founded order `<` between the tuples of values of these variables guarantee that the condition `E` is false eventually.

This is much easier to understand with actual verification systems in which it is possible to try out things. Read [this tutorial](http://frama-c.com/jessie/jessie-tutorial.pdf) up to section **2.3 Checking Termination** and see if the practical version of the same explanation makes more sense to you.

Comment: Thank you very much for the response.  I am still a bit confused; if I substitute y for x in an expression, which contains, among other things, "x < y" then I will get "y < y" which should never be true.

Comment: @Jove wp(…) is not a logic function. You cannot substitute inside its arguments. It is a meta-function (that takes logic terms as arguments).

Comment: Thank you.  Can I say the following: first obtain wp(S, I \wedge x < y), call this T, and then substitute y for x in ((E \wedge I) \implies T), so that x and y are both bound by the \forall y... ?

Comment: @Jove Yes, you can say that.

Comment: Could you guys please give a simple example of how you manage to make these textual substitions for a loop ? I have such an exercise to solve and I'm nearly desperate. Thanks in advance.